# Material UI V5 Theming Customization

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

How can i override this css of material ui ? i want to change de color to : white, becouse when i try to write on my TextField the color is black

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want ***just the text color to be white***

You can add `sx` prop for the TextField.

```
<TextField
  variant="outlined"
  sx={{
    '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
      color: 'white',
    },
  }}
/>
```

If you want to ***customize the default MUI theme***

1. Import **createTheme** and **ThemeProvider**.

   `import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';`
2. Override theme.
   (You can go to https://mui.com/customization/default-theme/ and find exactly what to override.)

   ```
    const theme = createTheme({
        palette: {
          common: {
            white: '#FFFAFA'
          },
        }
      })
   ```
3. Wrap Your Components or the TextField with `ThemeProvider`.

> ```
> <ThemeProvider theme={theme} >
>       <TextField
>         variant="outlined"
>         sx={{
>           '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
>             color: 'white',
>           },
>         }}
>       />
> </ThemeProvider>
> ```

The color 'white' in the TextField will be the white color that you customized.
You can also define a color palette for the application.

Refer [mui.com/customization/theming](https://mui.com/customization/theming/) for more details.

Here is a youtube Tutorial for this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIIJfmDnvPE&ab_channel=TheNetNinja

Answer (score 2):

If your custom style is overridden by Material UI you can just add !important; after each one of your custom styles.

Answer (score 2):

You can the sx on the props of the object:

```
<TextField id="outlined-basic" sx={{background:'red'}} label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
```

follow the link to see the props of sx: https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/

Answer (score 2):

See the docs for [overriding nested component styles](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-nested-component-styles).

For TextField that would be:

```js
<TextField
  variant="outlined"
  sx={{
    '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
      color: 'white',
    },
  }}
/>)
```